# Is an HTML5 file with lines beyond </html> valid?

Tags: html, browser, format

The following HTML5 page is correctly displayed by Chrome (version 52):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>

<br> <span style="color:cyan;">Text</span>
<br> <span style="color:red;">Text</span>
```

Is this valid HTML5 syntax?
Can I put those lines out of the  block?

Being HTML5 more rigid with syntax compared to HTML4, could it be that the browser accepts it anyway ignoring the error and violating the HTML5 specification?

Comment: Of course it isn’t valid. Every XML-like document needs to have a root node. Why don’t you just check this with an online HTML validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a browser will render and what is technically valid are different.  Valid html has a higher probability of working as expected across all browsers, most of which are being constantly upated.  The [validator](https://validator.w3.org) at the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) give 3 errors

- Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.
- Stray start tag br
- Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.

Comment: I added the head and the body, to focus on my issue (I oversimplified the HTML file).